# Implicit parameters in trailing closure

Tags: swift, closures

I'm somewhat new to Swift. Not a total beginner.

Is there a way to pass a closure as a parameter without explicitly filling out that closure's parameter list?

Trying this code from [here](https://abhimuralidharan.medium.com/higher-order-functions-in-swift-filter-map-reduce-flatmap-1837646a63e8):

```swift
func addition(num1: Double, num2: Double) -> Double {
    return num1 + num2
}
func multiply(num1: Double, num2: Double) -> Double {
    return num1 * num2
}
func doMathOperation(operation:( _ x:Double, _ y:Double) -> Double, num1: Double, num2: Double) -> Double {
    return operation(num1, num2)
}
doMathOperation(operation: multiply, num1: 4, num2: 5) //20
doMathOperation(operation: addition, num1: 4, num2: 5) //9
```

So I thought I'd rewrite it to make it easier to read:

```swift
func addition (_ num1: Double, _ num2: Double)->Double {
    return num1 + num2
}
func multiply (_ num1: Double, _ num2: Double)->Double {
    return num1 * num2
}
func doMathOperation(_ num1: Double, _ num2: Double, operation: (_ x:Double,_ y:Double)->Double) ->Double {
    return operation(num1, num2)
}
```

Interestingly, this works:

```swift
doMathOperation(4, 5, operation: multiply) //20
```

But this doesn't:

```swift
doMathOperation(4, 5) {multiply} //error: contextual type for closure argument list expects 2 arguments, which cannot be implicitly ignored
```

As far as I know, they should mean the exact same thing, but when I use trailing closure syntax, the compiler won't let me compile it.

Comment: "As far as I know, they should mean the exact same thing" - how do you figure? One is passing a named closure as a parameter; the other - is providing and in-place defining an anonymous closure. Where have you ever seen a function's body implicitly applying its parameters to its body statement, which happens to be a named closure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
doMathOperation(4, 5, operation: multiply)
```

...you are being asked for a function that takes two Double parameters, and `multiply` is the name of just such a function, so it compiles and works.

In

```
doMathOperation(4, 5) { ... }
```

the *curly braces themselves* are the (body of the) function that takes two Double parameters. It makes no sense to put the name of *another* such function inside the curly braces.

But of course you are free to *call* any function you like, passing along the parameters that were passed to you; hence this works:

```
doMathOperation(4, 5) { multiply($0,$1) }
```

So, just to sum up: In the first one

```
doMathOperation(4, 5, operation: multiply)
```

there is one function, `multiply`, and 4 and 5 are passed to it. In the second one

```
doMathOperation(4, 5) { multiply($0,$1) }
```

there are two functions, "anonymous" (the curly braces) and `multiply`, and the 4 and 5 are passed into the first one and then it calls the second one.

Comment: I could rattle on for quite a long time about the different ways you can express what goes into the `operation:` parameter and what goes into the curly braces, but I think what I've said is the most direct answer to the particular aspect of the matter you raise, so I'll stop for now.

Comment: Thanks matt. That makes sense, trailing closure is asking for the body and not the enclosing variable that holds the body. So if I understand correctly, trailing closure syntax is not shorthand for non-trailing closure syntax, i.e. it's not another way of saying the exact same thing. In trailing closure syntax, is there a way to pass a named closure like `multiply` without passing it inside of `anonymous`? I'm looking for a way (if possible) to pass a closure, in trailing closure syntax, without having to pass in the arguments.

Comment: I don’t get what you mean. A function, whether named or anonymous, is a closure. If you want to pass a name, use the first notation. If you want to pass an anonymous function body, you can use either notation. But the name of a function cannot trail outside the parentheses, only an anonymous function body can do that. That is what trailing closure syntax means.

Comment: To put it another way: Swift is a language, with rules. I can imagine a language in which you could "trail" a bare function name, but I don't see what the point would be (it is no advantage over normal parameter syntax), and in any case, that language would not be Swift. If you want to use Swift, you must obey _its_ rules, not some other rules that you make up in your head.